# uninitialized local variable 'j' used

Tags: c++, error-handling, variable-assignment

Here is a section of some code I have. Im getting an error uninitialized local variable 'j' used and I dont see it. as far as I can tell it is being used. Can someone please help?

```
float Calculate(Element ElmAry[30], Formula FormAry[30])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    float MoleWT = 0;
    float MoleSum = 0;
    char e1;
    char e2;
    char f1;
    char f2;

    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

        f1 = FormAry[j].Element1;
        f2 = FormAry[j].ElementA;
        e1 = ElmAry[i].eN1;
        e2 = ElmAry[i].eN1;

        if(e1 == f1 && e2 == f2) {
            MoleWT = ElmAry[i].Weight * FormAry[j].Atom;
            MoleSum = MoleSum + MoleWT;
            j++;
        }
    }

return MoleSum;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So you use the variable `j` first in the line

```
f1 = FormAry[j].Element1;
```

But you haven't assigned any value to `j` previously, hence "uninitialized". The previous mention of `j` was in your declaration:

```
int j;
```

You need to assign a value to it, like 0:

```
int j = 0;
```

That is call "initialization", because if you don't assign any value to a variable, what value should you expect from that variable?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't given `j` a value, hence the `uninitialized variable` error.

`int j;` is not the same as assigning `j` a value of 0.

You should do: `int j = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

The error isn't that `j` is being used.  The error is that `j` is being used but it isn't being initialized.

I suggest changing your `for` loop to:

```
for(i=0, j=0; i < 30; i++, j++)
```

As I think this is probably what you're actually trying to do...