# Changing behavior of "uninitialized local variable" error

Tags: c++, global-variables

Consider the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  int count123;
  for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
  {
    count123 += c;
  }

    return 0;
}
```

Upon compilation I get the warning: `warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'count123' used`

I know the [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19106701/5022962) is declaring count123 but not initializing it.

But if I declare count123 as a global variable as in the code below, the warning disappears.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int count123;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

  for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
  {
    count123 += c;
  }

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I know declaring count123 as a global variable would change its scope but how does that remove the warning? Please guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The global variables are zero initialized (by the way, the same applies to statics variables). THis is why you don't get this message.

Here the standard quote:

> **8.5/10:** Every object of static storage duration is zero-initialized at program startup before any other initialization
>   takes place. In some cases, additional initialization is done later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Christophe. Please clarify what do you mean by "as well as the statics"

Comment: He means Static variables are also initialized with zero,

Comment: @Nishant exactly.  I've changed the wording to avoid the confusion.  The exact terms of the standard is "variables with static storage duration" which covers global variables and static variables.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are initialized by zero always, think of a global pointer, initialized with some random value, and you used it in your code mistakenly.
 Global initialization makes it NULL, so you can check it and use accordingly.

> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
>   unsigned) zero;

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are static storage variables and these are by default zero-initialized. For more information, please see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328655/why-doesnt-the-compiler-give-an-error-when-an-uninitialized-variable-is-returne).

Answer (score 1):

The global variables are initialized with *zero* by default, hence you got no warnings.

You can easily get the draft of [C++ standards](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) then read the section ***8.5 Initializers:***

> 10
>   [ Note: Every object of static storage duration is zero-initialized at program startup before any other initialization takes place. In some cases, additional initialization is done later. —end note ]