# Uninitialized local variable 'OnSpeed' Used

Tags: c++, initialization

**Hello people came here because I have a problem in a code that I'm changing.**

**I'm using Visual Studio 2015**

the code is giving this issue

> Uninitialized local variable 'OnSpeed' used
>
> Uninitialized local variable 'OnBM2' used
>
> Uninitialized local variable 'OnCombo' used
>
> Uninitialized local variable 'OnNSD' used

```
 #include <windows.h>
 #include "MyCheat.h"

 void Start()
{
   bool OnSpeed, OnBM2, OnCombo, OnNSD;
   char * CAPTION = "My Sample DLL";

   while (true)
  {
     //================================ CHANGE NATION      ===================================================
    if (GetKeyState(VK_F11) < 0) { CHANGE_NATION(); }
    //==================================================================================================

    //================================ MOVEMENT SPEED ==================================================
    if (GetKeyState(VK_F12) < 0)
    {
        if (!OnSpeed) {
            OnSpeed = true;
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Movement Speed ON", CAPTION, MB_OK);
        }
        else {
            OnSpeed = false;
            MOVE_SPEED(450.0);
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Movement Speed OFF", CAPTION, MB_OK);
        }
    }
    //==================================================================================================

    //THIS BM2, COMBO AND NSD IS ONLY WORK IN WIN 7 32BIT AND 64BIT

    //================================ NO COOLDOWN BM2 =================================================
    if (GetKeyState(VK_F10) < 0)
    {
        if (!OnBM2) {
            OnBM2 = true;
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "No Cooldown BM2 ON", CAPTION, MB_OK);
        }
        else {
            OnBM2 = false;
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "No Cooldown BM2 OFF", CAPTION, MB_OK);
        }
    }
    //==================================================================================================

    //================================ PERFECT COMBO ===================================================
    if (GetKeyState(VK_F9) < 0)
    {
        if (!OnCombo) {
            OnCombo = true;
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "PERFECT COMBO ON", CAPTION, MB_OK);
        }
        else {
            OnCombo = false;
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "PERFECT COMBO OFF", CAPTION, MB_OK);
        }
    }
    //==================================================================================================

    //================================ NO SKILL DELAY ==================================================
    if (GetKeyState(VK_F8) < 0)
    {
        if (!OnNSD) {
            OnNSD = true;
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "No Skill Delay ON", CAPTION, MB_OK);
        }
        else {
            OnNSD = false;
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "No Skill Delay OFF", CAPTION, MB_OK);
        }
    }
    //==================================================================================================

    //================================ FREEZING VALUE ==================================================
    if (OnSpeed) MOVE_SPEED(600.0);
    if (OnBM2) NOCD_BM2();
    if (OnCombo) NOCD_COMBO();
    if (OnNSD) NSD();
    //==================================================================================================

    Sleep(1);
}
```

}

Comment: What is unclear about this error message (or, more precisely, warning)?

Comment: Those variables are not initialized, like error says.

Comment: The *first* time you get to `if (!OnSpeed)`, what value does it have? None so far...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uninitialized local variable 'j' used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106689/uninitialized-local-variable-j-used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message could not be clearer.

In C++, you have to initialize local variables in order to use them. They do not have a default value.

You have to assign a value to `OnSpeed`, `OnBM2`, `OnCombo`, `OnNSD` first.